# laravel update one filed with another field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

all
I am using laravel 5 and my code is like this

```
$assign = Assign::where('kh','=',$product->kh)->update(['plan_assign_amount' => 'ROUND(single_sales_rate*'.($skuCounts*2).')']);
```

so that's quite easy and actually in mysql statment ,my sql string is like this

```
update `assign` set `plan_assign_amount` = ROUND(single_sales_rate*18);
```

but it couldn't work,so is there a simple way to do it ?or only use DB:update() to run a raw sql?

thanks for help;

Comment: Is this update for multiple rows or single item?

Comment: What is `$skuCounts` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could run raw db query with `DB::statement`,`DB::raw` or `DB::update` or you could try to do something like this:

```
$assign = Assign::where('kh', '=', $product->kh)->first();
$assign->update(['plan_assign_amount' => round($assign->single_sales_rate * $skuCounts * 2)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

find the answer is

```
$assign = DB::table('assign')->where('kh','=',$product->kh)->update(['plan_assign_amount' => DB::raw('ROUND(single_sales_rate*'.($skuCounts*2).')')]);
```

that works fine !!